# English Literature site is not indexing new pages in google

Tags: google-search-console

This is my site link:
[www.englishact.com](http://www.englishact.com)

This is the sitemap current position:
[image]

Google is showing no error in sitemap or any other pages. But indexed pages are 0 for about 3 months. I also have uploaded new sitemaps which are acting same way with no index.

NB:

I am using 1and1 paid hosting package. Also, google has accepted adsence for this site.  Now what can I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is index on Google, i just searched for site: www.englishact.com and got many results.

Check if the links in your XML sitemap are valid or redirecting to another URL.

Also you have to solve the duplication in the URLs, you can access your website with WWW and without it, also you have two URLs for the homepage http://englishact.com/ and http://www.englishact.com/index.php

After fixing these errors your website should be healthy and Google will understand the structure of it.